# Posts deleted since 2nd June 2014 can no longer be found via a search of `deleted:1`

Tags: bug, search, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

As a mod on https://ux.stackexchange.com/ I often do a search of `deleted:1` to see what posts have been removed that I may not know about, or to refresh my memory of any spammy nonsense. Just doing a general check of the state of the site to see what's been going on.

However, doing so today I am not seeing anything since the end of May 2014.

A check with the mods from some other sites seem to say this is happening elsewhere too.

- No deleted posts on Webapps since 1st June
- No deleted posts on DIY since 1st June
- No deleted posts on Programmers since 1st June

And even on StackOverflow the last one to appear in `deleted:1` search is from the 2nd June.

So what is going on? Have they been completely expunged from the known universe? Or is the `deleted:1` search string no longer the one to use - and if so, how do we find deleted posts nowadays?

Comment: Search is broken in all Stack Exchange sites. (using old data, up to June 2 when they moved servers)

Comment: Ah yes, I should've broadened my MSE search from just looking for reported issues around the deleted:1 string. (Although not sure I'd have found it anyway, what with Search not working correctly!)

Comment: No worry, I also fail to search on sites I don't roam frequently, just posted a glaring dupe on arqade meta. ;-(

Comment: "... to see what posts have been removed that I may not know about, or to refresh my memory of any spammy nonsense" Heh, the only reason I ever search for `deleted:1` is for the cheap laughs ;P

Comment: @Yannis: It started as cheap laughs. Then it just got depressing. Searching `deleted:1` should really be renamed `search:facepalm posts` for the volume of spam or 'did they *really* post that?` type Q/As.